# process has died [pid 8941, exit code 127, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-11, launch-file, ros-gazebo

I am launching gazebo with `ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py` Gazebo is not launched and is showing the following error:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/dell/.ros/log/2023-09-17-13-44-45-896306-ubuntu22-8940
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [8941]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [8943]
[gzserver-1] gzserver: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libtrajectory_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN36rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp31get_message_type_support_handleIN13geometry_msgs3msg10Transform_ISaIvEEEEEPK29rosidl_message_type_support_tv
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 8941, exit code 127, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 8943, exit code 255, cmd 'gzclient'].
```

all packages and plugins for gazebo-ros are installed by `sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `ros2_ws` and recreated it again. `colcon build` and error solved

Comment: It is usually suffcient to delete the top-level `build` and `install` directories. The most recent versions of colcon also have a `clean` command.

Comment: Yes, this also works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue as well (Ubuntu, Humble) - for some reason a reboot resolved it. Go figure.